# Am I using the word 'arbitrarily' correctly?

Tags: vocabulary

For example, if I were to say:

> "What? Just because I was arbitrarily born as an Asian, that means I have to stick with my own kind?"

If that is wrong, how would I change it so it makes sense? Is there a way I can still use the word 'arbitrarily'? I'm really just trying to figure out how to use the word.

Comment: I think arbitrariness requires the action of an agent.

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

> Just because I happened to be born Asian, that means I have to stick with my own kind?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to rearrange the sentence to still use the word 'arbitrarily' or does the word just not belong in this context?

Comment: @dsgnmnky No, probably not.

Comment: @dsgnmnky Don't insist upon using a word merely because you think it's cool, interesting, or attractive in some way. You should always be seeking the best word for the given purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by changing the wording of your question quite significantly, you could come up with the following:

> Can you blame me for resenting people who decide arbitrarily that my being born Asian means I have to stick with my own kind?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can say that!

However, when you say it, it bears a meaning. It bears that you believe in either an Almighty Singularity, an ancient alien force who created you and your fellow humans, or the sentient lucky almighty flying spaghetti.

By using *arbitrarily*, you are blaming that Someone for having made you Asian, and arbitrarily so. How unlucky! So, if you don't want to project yourself as a self-hating bigot, you should not use that word that way.

On the other hand, if you persist in hurting yourself, this would be the properly comprehensible way to say it.

> "What? Just because I was arbitrarily born as an Asian, would that mean I have to stick with my own kind?"

This inquisitive structure sounds very street-wise English that you would encounter in parts of English-speaking Asia. And, among Europeans or Russians who are not native to speaking English.

> Just because I am a girl, that means I have to get married?

This structure is not fluent as a question. It is an affirmative statement.

> Just because I am a girl, that means I have to get married. It has always been that way in our society.

Therefore, your sentence structure actually says,

> Just because I was arbitrarily born as an Asian, that means I have to stick with my own kind! You cannot talk me out of it. I have to do it.

However, if you wish to avoid hurting yourself, I recommend the following

- Holy cow! Just because I was lucky enough to be born Asian, should I restrict myself to my vicinity of ethnicity?
- Cheeezus! Did Whoever that had arbitrarily allowed me the privilege of being born Asian ever told me to restrict myself to go forth and socialise or multiply only within my own ethnicity?
- WTF! Did the Almighty Evolutionary process, which brought me forth into the world as an Asian, EVER once dictated a rule that we have to socialise within our own kind? Even if it did, I intend to violate that rule. Good luck stopping me.

Let me remind you that the following has a non-fluent structure:

> Just because I am a girl, does not mean I have to get married.

It is like saying,

> I am going to the moon, does not mean I have to like space travel.

It is more fluent to say

- {Something gerund-ish} does not mean I have to get married.
- My going to the moon does not require that I have to like space travel
- Being a girl does not mean I have to get married.
- Does looking like an idiot qualify you as a stand-up comedian?
- Does having been arbitrarily born an Asian automatically qualify me with great academic performance?
- Does attending a Russell Peters performance require me to appreciate his jokes?